# Перевод кода с C++ на Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi

Есть такой код на c++

```
PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER PImage;
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS PNTHead;
...
PImage=(PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)(PNTHead+1);
```

Как можно перевести на Delphi?
`PNTHead+1` будет тоже самое что и `Inc(PNTHead)` в Delphi?

Comment: А вы попробуйте и посмотрите, будет указатель куда надо указывать или нет. Это быстрее и проще чем спрашивать ;-)

Comment: Мне кажется что такой сложный механизм не нужно реализовывать на delphi. Сравните управление адресным пространством в delphi и в c++. К сожелению в delphi нету "прямого преобразования". Вам прийдётся переписывать это.

Comment: Выражение `(PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)(PNTHead+1);` Можно переписать на с++ как    `(PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER) (((char*)PNTHead) + sizeof(*PNTHead))` а на делфи что-то вроде    `PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER (integer(PNTHead) + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS) )`

Comment: к `NativeInt` приводить надо в современных версиях